# Deal with CSS and JS when redirecting to a friendly URL

Tags: javascript, php, css, friendly-url

I have this example url: **mypage.com/notices.php**. Inside I have a list of notices and to access them you clic one and the url turns on a friendly one exactly like this: **mypage.com/notices/title-of-my-notice**. But my problem is when I am accessing to that url because my CSS and JS that worked properly in notices.php now doesn't work with the new friendly url and shows me this mistake:

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "mypage.com/notices/css/styles.css".

And my styles aren't in that route. The are here: mypage.com/css/styles.css. The same happens with my JS files.

I want to know in which way I can deal with it because I don't know if the solution is to call the full URL when calling my stylesheet on my webpage or there is another way.

Thx.

Comment: Use an absolute url for the assets, or add a `base` tag, but that brings its own issues

Comment: Steve thx. So, you mean that I must use something like this: <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mypage.com/css/styles.css" />

Comment: Yes that would be the safest bet

Comment: And when I use images which route is on database, is the correct way to save on the database like this: mypage.com/img/myimage.jpg or just myimage.jpg and then I link together with the name of my page. Because as happens with CSS and JS, the same is with IMG.

Comment: Personally i would have the domain as a variable, eg `$url = 'http://mypage.com';` then build the full url using that variable. Then if you move your site to a different domain you only have to update one variable

Comment: Thx Steve. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Create a link that is relative to the root using a `/` check markup below:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: Thank you! The same happens with images which are saved on database? For example I stored them like this: myimage.jpg and when I retrieve it by SQL query I just link together the name of my page like this: mypage.com/img/myimage.jpg. Is a good practice doing that?

Comment: If you have 'image.jpg' saved in the database, I would create a url like this "/img/myimage.jpg" and put it in the src tags. The great thing about relative urls is they don't break if you change the domain they run on.

Comment: Thx clean_coding have a nice day!